# No "Personnal Folder" when querying the Folder through SOQL

Tags: soql, rest-api

I'm using the Salesforce REST API and when I do the following query, it doesn't return the "My personnal folder", hence I don't get its ID :

```
SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate FROM Folder
```

Is there any way I can return the list of folders (with their IDs) including the "My personnal folder" ?

Thanks for your answers.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Personal Folder" of a user is their user ID. It won't appear in a Folder query, because it doesn't "actually" exist in that sense; FolderId is actually a polymorphic field in places where it appears that can accept a Folder ID or User ID. This includes reports, templates, and documents.

Comment: If the "Personnal Folder" doesn't exist as such, how can I get its attribute "LastModifiedDate" ?

Comment: @Asticode The only possibly relevant LastModifiedDate might be the user's LastModifiedDate, because that folder doesn't exist as an actual folder, nor can you "modify" that folder.